# How to add muliple AND and Where in a single Query

Tags: javascript, mysql

How to add muliple AND and Where in a single Query

Date2 = newDate.today();

```
Select Name from tbl Where (" DER ")  AND EntryStatus ='GUEST' AND Date = "+ Date2 +";
```

Comment: what is `(" DER ")`?

Comment: DER is a unique name

Comment: you wanted to do like name = 'DER' ?

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want and what has javascript to do with this question?

Comment: Need to get the name of the customers where the shop name ='DER' and EntryStatus='GUEST' and Date= todays date

Comment: How you execute this query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select IntName from tbl Where  name ="DDL2"  AND EntryStatus ='GUEST' AND Date = '" +Date2+"' ;

Answer (score 0):

Could be you mean `name = ("DER")`

```
Select Name from tbl Where name = "DER"  AND EntryStatus ='GUEST' AND Date =  CURDATE();
```

Comment: I have update the answer with the proper mysql code  .. but could be you are try to do somethings else with javascript  ..